# Fluent Assertions Should().BeEquivalentTo with only private field

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, tdd, fluent-assertions

Try to compare objects with single private field

Object like this:

```
public struct A
{
    private readonly byte[] bytes;

    public A(byte[] bytes)
    {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
}
```

Compare this way:

```
var a = new A(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
var b = new A(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);
```

Result:

```
Message: Expected a to be 

A
{
}, but found 

A
{
}.
```

Сan I get a positive comparison without override `Equals`?

Comment: You shouldn't assert on private members. There should be a public member that exposes a change in behaviour when `bytes` is different. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586/247702

Comment: @Stijn , it seems that I have an ambiguous case, object `A` is unique id, and it's field of other object in my code. Sound weird, but in all by case i does't compare unique id with other unique ids (store it in database like byte array, get byte array via `MyUniqueId.GetByteArray()`). So it look like I will overload `Equals` only for tests,

Comment: So `A` has a method `GetByteArray()`? If so, you should write a unit test for that method instead of implementing `Equals()` I think.

Comment: Yes, `A` has a method `GetByteArray()`, but in my test I compare objects that contain `A`: `class B { public A Id {get;} ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're comparing structs, which is [treated](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#value-types) by FA as a type with value semantics, FA will use the compiler-generated `Equals` implementation. In this case, your structs contain two different instances of a `byte[]` array, so they will never match. Also, FA will never report or access the values of private fields. Why would it if you decided it to be private? And you didn't override `ToString` in any suitable way.

So the only way to make this work is to add a `public` or `internal` property, or to implement `Equals` correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22995842)

Comment: Rephrased my solution.